# Displaying image on clicked location on picturebox in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, image

I want an image to be inserted when I clicked on specific location on picturebox. the image shows when I put coordinates in number form in the code below.

```
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("myImage.gif"), New Point(10, 10))
```

But what I want is that the coordinates is retrieved when I click on a specific location and put it on a variable. But the image is not displaying with this code, I just replaced the number 10,10 with a variable.

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseDown

    myX = e.X
    myY = e.Y

    g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("myImage.gif"),New Point(myX, myY))

End Sub
```

Why is it not working ? Any idea sirs.

Answer (score 0):

You need coordinates relative to the form. e.X, e.Y And Cursor.Position, they all supply global coordinates. Thus, set the relative coordinates using:

```
g.DrawImage(Image.FromFile("myImage.gif"), Me.PointToClient(Cursor.Position))
```

Comment: I dont understand sir. Can you please elaborate

Comment: global coordinates are those which correspond to the whole screen. relative coordinates mean that they are relative to the form, i.e., not for the whole screen. E.g. - global coordinates (10,10) refer to a location from the top-left extreme corner of your screen which may point to another window or something. but relative coordinates (10, 10) will mean ten pixel distances from the top left extreme corner of your form. Thus, if you use global coordinates, they will only work if your application is full-screen. hope it helps :-)